# Log to file output of an exec() command triggered from php

Tags: php, logging, error-handling, exec, imagick

I have a php script to convert PDF files to images using imagick.

It works on my local box but in the production server it fails to execute the command but not sure about the reason because I can't see my command execution output.

No SSH access or to the admin panel.

In order to solve this I need to know how can I log to a text file the output of this command execution in the shell from my php script, so I can after the fail download it by ftp and read it.

```
exec('convert -density 150 -quality 100 -sharpen 0x2.0 -background white -alpha remove ' . $file->getFileInfo()->getRealPath() . ' ' . $save_to, $result, $error);
```

`$result` variable I tried to `print_r($result);` and it just shows me  `Array ()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**`shell_exec()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) which does same as [**`exec()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and will outputs for you the results to check where is the error by doing it this way.

```
$error = shell_exec('convert -density 150 -quality 100 -sharpen 0x2.0 -background white -alpha remove ' . $file->getFileInfo()->getRealPath() . ' ' . $save_to . ' 2>&1');

print_r($error);

exit;
```

Comment: This does the trick, now I know the problem is the ImageMagick on the server is very old, and this one lacks from the -alpha option I'm using in my command.