# PHP exec() not working with a >> in command

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to run an exec command via PHP script like this -

`exec("php script.php >> log.txt");`

However it doesn't work. It works when the command is -

`exec("php script.php");`

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try with : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25280163/log-to-file-output-of-an-exec-command-triggered-from-php

Comment: Why you say it now works, it works well for me. My script.php is `<?php
echo 'aaaaaa';` and my test.php is `<?php
exec("php script.php >> log.txt");`. Both the file is in the user directory. When I run `php test.php`, it works. You should make sure the file path, and the execution privelege.

Comment: Thing is that log.txt may not be writable

Comment: I am such a dummy... the file was not writeable :(
Thanks for pointing this out!